# Typing Romanian characters in Vim in Windows 7

Tags: windows, vim, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Romanian keyboard with gVim](https://superuser.com/questions/290532/using-romanian-keyboard-with-gvim)

I'm using Vim 7.3 in Windows 7, with the keyboard set to Romanian (Programmers). In the console and any other program, right-alt + s generates ș (s with comma below). In Vim it generates a question mark. Can anyone explain why? And what can I do to have Vim recognize this character (and t with comma below)?

Comment: I've posted an answer on a similar question here: http://superuser.com/a/368269/109693

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Vim, but I'm sure it can handle Unicode properly. The problem might be font related. If the font used by Vim does not support the Romanian charset, you get `?` on the screen (even though, internally the correct character is stored).

You can verify this by copying the question mark from Vim and pasting it into another program that can can display such characters. If it's shown correctly, the culprit is Vim's font.

Comment: I'm using Consolas, it can display those characters correctly (I opened in Vim a file created in Notepad with all the Romanian diacritics). And the character inserted when I type in Vim is really an ASCII question mark, not some other character missing in the font.